# How to add count of subjects in panel using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, summary

I want to add a text `like N=xx`, where `XX` is the count of distinct subjects in each dose level and should be calculated automatically for each dose and panel.

Can anyone help me please?

[image]

Comment: You could create a summary_df, and use that in `annotate` or `geom_text`.

Comment: If you posted your code, someone would probably show you how, but making up the **whole** thing is just too speculative. You could get to this image in a couple of different ways.